# fixed effects as categorical data and how to interparete the results?

Tags: interpretation, fixed-effects-model, glmm

I have trouble undestanding how to interpret my results. Working with glmm and poisson (link) models.
I found one example that is given for negative binomial and how they interpret the results: "Every one-unit increase in the value of math, then daysabs(y) will decrease (-) by 0.9940249 times, provided that other predictor variables are constant"

Based on that and looking at my results I could say that: "Every one-unit increase in the value of Field_A1, then birds_count(y) will decrease (-) by 1.4288 times, provided that other predictor variables are constant.

But here i have a small problem, as my variables are categorical/factors and not a numeric outcomes. So it dosen't make sensce that if Field_A1 increases (as it can not increas in area size, or whatever, it constant) the bird_count can't decrese either.

From the analysis I would like to know:

- How two fixed effects (Field & Distance) are affecting abundace. If distance increases the abundace or not? Is ther a difference in abundace depending on the field type?
- How two fixed effects (Field & Distance) interaction is affecting the abundace

Can anyone help me?

Example of the estimates and the code I am using:

Data explanatsion:

- LS - total 18 sectors in landscape
- Field_Type- is a factor
  (A1;A2;A3). A1- grassland; A2-production field; A3- not sown area
- Distance- 50m, 75m, 150m, 200m
- sampling.round - total 3 rounds, so in three different time points were the data collected
- abundace- in that spot counted number of individuals

```
model1<- glmmTMB(Abundace~Field_Type +distance+Field_Type*distance+(1|sampling.round)+(1|LS),
                      family=poisson(link="log"), data=OWL6) # with interaction model used
```

```
                              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                      0.7480     0.6922   1.081 0.279918    
Field_A1                        -1.4288     0.5392  -2.650 0.008052 ** 
Field_A2                        -0.2888     0.4766  -0.606 0.544524    
distance_50m                    -0.4925     0.1712  -2.877 0.004009 ** 
Field_A2:distance_50m            1.8741     0.3247   5.772 7.82e-09 ***
```

Example of the data:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information about your study? What are the explanatory variables, what is the outcome variable? Presumably you made observations in three different fields (A0, A1, A2) and it's not meaningful to think about one-unit increase in the value of Field_A1. Also there is an interaction term Field_A2:distance_50m but we would expect an interaction Field_A1:distance_50m as well.

Comment: Finally, in a model with interactions it's not meaningful to interpret the main effects on their own without taking the interaction into account. It might be easier if you explained what questions you want to answer with your model.

Comment: I added just a small part of the output, not the full, just to show the idea of the results. 
But my study is looking at different field types that are around field (that why there are A1, A2, but also there is A3), so I have 3 field types, and also the sampling locatsion could affect it. sampling location (distances) i have in total 4, so I am looking at their interactions also.  So my main question is there anykind of difference in the number on individuals based on the field type and locatsion of sampling, and is these factors decreasing or increasing the abundace

Comment: So the two fixed effects (Field & Distance) are categorical, with an interaction between the two. So you could compare E{Y} between fields at a given distance and also compare E{Y} between distances in a given field. (I don't quite understand what the response Y is but it's a count of something). I find this approach more intuitive than looking at the coefficient estimates in the summary table. In any case, since the fixed effects are categorical, you cannot change either of them by 1 unit.

Comment: Yes your correct on what I want to know based on this analysis. But is this even a right approche I am doing? Or should I just say that these factors (based on ANOVA) have an effect but I cannot see the effect size? What would you reccomend I do?

Comment: I admit I cannot understand what you are doing. You say you've fitted a Poisson GLMM. Now you mention ANOVA and effect sizes. What would help to get a more specific answer is to provide data (the actual data or simulated data that "looks like" your data or data from a previous study etc.) Some relevant details are still not clear. (And you should edit your question to add relevant information; the comments are not the right place for that.)

Comment: Edited the question. Regarding the ANOVA - What I was refering to was should I just test the hypotheses of my analysis questions (if these two factors have a effect on abundace or not), and not go into glmm summary so much? Effect size - I would like to see, if Field type A has a postive or negative effect as estimates can show whether there is an postive or negative effect on intercept, but I don't think this applicable on my analysis

Comment: Thank you for the update! From the portion of the data attached, it seems that Field_Type is given by `A{LS}`. Is this the case? Why do you have a random effect `(1|LS)`? Similarly, does "round" mean something like "replicate"? How many replicates do you have? And why is there a random effect `(1|sampling.round)`?

Comment: updated the post, to expalin the data more

Answer (score 0):

In a model with interactions, you cannot study the main effects separately from the interactions. So instead of the two questions: (a) How the two main effects (Field & Distance) affect abundance? (b) How the Field × Distance interaction affects abundance, you can study (a) differences in abundance between fields at a given distance, and (b) differences in abundance between distances in each field type.

This means that rather than looking at the estimated model parameters (the coefficients you get with the `summary` function in R), it's more constructive to compare estimated marginal means, ie. E{Abundance | Field, Distance}.

It helps to illustrate this suggestion with an example. So I'll simulate data under the experimental setup described in the question. Here are the parameters I'm going to use. (I have no idea whether the chosen parameter values are at all realistic.) The *rate* is the average abundance for a given Field × Distance combination, ie. E{Abundance | Field, Distance}. Note that Field and Distance interact for Field = "grassland" and "production" but not for Field = "not sown".

```r
params <- tribble(
  ~Field_Type, ~distance, ~rate,
  "not sown", "50m", 0.2,
  "not sown", "75m", 0.2,
  "not sown", "150m", 0.2,
  "not sown", "200m", 0.2,
  "grassland", "50m", 1,
  "grassland", "75m", 1,
  "grassland", "150m", 1,
  "grassland", "200m", 3,
  "production", "50m", 1,
  "production", "75m", 2,
  "production", "150m", 2,
  "production", "200m", 4
)
```

The mock dataset is generated from a Poisson model with known parameters, so I don't need to check that the Poisson model is appropriate for the data. In their analysis, the OP should verify that the Poisson model is a reasonable fit to the actual data; this is an important and non-trivial step.

Next we fit the Poisson generalized linear mixed model (GLMM). I include a random sector effect, `(1|LS)`, but not a random sampling round effect. I omit `(1|sampling.round)` because the description "the three different time points when the data was collected" suggests to me that data was collected at three different times but not necessarily at exactly the same three times for all combinations of Field × Distance. Also, it simplifies the simulation a bit. In any case, the structure of the random effects makes no difference for how analyze & compare the fixed effects in the model.

```r
model1 <- glmmTMB(
  Abundace ~ Field_Type + distance + Field_Type * distance + (1 | LS),
  family = poisson(link = "log"),
  data = OWL6
)
```

Once we fit the model, we can easily get the estimated model coefficients. It's not obvious how these coefficients are related to the rates E{Y | Field, Distance}. Interpreting the coefficients is challenging because (a) the coefficients depend on the parametrization: "not sown" and "50m" are the reference Field & Distance levels and don't appear in the summary table; (b) there are interactions, so we cannot vary a main effect while "keeping all other predictors fixed"; and (c) since this is a generalized model with a $\log$ link, the coefficients are on the log scale, $\log\text{rate}$, not on the original abundance scale.

```r
summary(model1)
#>                                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)                        -1.4253     0.2776  -5.134 2.84e-07 ***
#> Field_Typegrassland                 1.4053     0.3095   4.541 5.61e-06 ***
#> Field_Typeproduction                1.4424     0.3084   4.677 2.91e-06 ***
#> distance75m                        -0.3677     0.4336  -0.848 0.396429    
#> distance150m                        0.2076     0.3734   0.556 0.578151    
#> distance200m                       -0.1671     0.4097  -0.408 0.683440    
#> Field_Typegrassland:distance75m     0.5083     0.4725   1.076 0.282068    
#> Field_Typeproduction:distance75m    1.0966     0.4637   2.365 0.018028 *  
#> Field_Typegrassland:distance150m   -0.2861     0.4227  -0.677 0.498520    
#> Field_Typeproduction:distance150m   0.5808     0.4073   1.426 0.153833    
#> Field_Typegrassland:distance200m    1.2337     0.4395   2.807 0.005003 ** 
#> Field_Typeproduction:distance200m   1.5396     0.4366   3.526 0.000421 ***
```

We can avoid all these challenges by interpreting the estimated marginal means instead of the model coefficients. That is, interpret the estimated rates E{Y | Field, Distance} instead of the estimated coefficients $\widehat{\beta}$s. I'll use the [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) package to do the calculations.

First let's look at the estimated rates:

```r
emm <- emmeans(model1, c("Field_Type", "distance"), type = "response")
emm
#>  Field_Type distance  rate     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
#>  not sown   50m      0.240 0.0668 Inf    0.1395     0.414
#>  grassland  50m      0.980 0.1352 Inf    0.7481     1.285
#>  production 50m      1.017 0.1377 Inf    0.7801     1.326
#>  not sown   75m      0.166 0.0555 Inf    0.0866     0.320
#>  grassland  75m      1.128 0.1451 Inf    0.8768     1.452
#>  production 75m      2.108 0.1992 Inf    1.7520     2.537
#>  not sown   150m     0.296 0.0741 Inf    0.1812     0.483
#>  grassland  150m     0.906 0.1300 Inf    0.6842     1.200
#>  production 150m     2.238 0.2053 Inf    1.8696     2.679
#>  not sown   200m     0.203 0.0614 Inf    0.1126     0.368
#>  grassland  200m     2.848 0.2322 Inf    2.4276     3.342
#>  production 200m     4.013 0.2770 Inf    3.5057     4.595
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

Since this is a simulation, we know the true rates, so let's plot the true rates (indicated by ×'s) alongside the estimated rates.

[image]

In practice, we don't know the true rates. Instead we can compare rates between field types for each distances, and between distances for each field type. That's a lot of pairwise comparisons because there are 3 field types and 4 distances.

```r
contrast(emm, "pairwise", by = "distance", adjust = "mvt")
#> distance = 50m:
#>  contrast                ratio     SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  not sown / grassland   0.2453 0.0759 Inf    1  -4.541  <.0001
#>  not sown / production  0.2364 0.0729 Inf    1  -4.677  <.0001
#>  grassland / production 0.9636 0.1855 Inf    1  -0.192  0.9793
#> 
#> distance = 75m:
#>  contrast                ratio     SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  not sown / grassland   0.1475 0.0527 Inf    1  -5.359  <.0001
#>  not sown / production  0.0789 0.0273 Inf    1  -7.333  <.0001
#>  grassland / production 0.5351 0.0849 Inf    1  -3.942  0.0002
#> 
#> distance = 150m:
#>  contrast                ratio     SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  not sown / grassland   0.3265 0.0940 Inf    1  -3.887  0.0003
#>  not sown / production  0.1322 0.0352 Inf    1  -7.606  <.0001
#>  grassland / production 0.4050 0.0686 Inf    1  -5.339  <.0001
#> 
#> distance = 200m:
#>  contrast                ratio     SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  not sown / grassland   0.0714 0.0223 Inf    1  -8.456  <.0001
#>  not sown / production  0.0507 0.0157 Inf    1  -9.649  <.0001
#>  grassland / production 0.7097 0.0748 Inf    1  -3.255  0.0028
#> 
#> P value adjustment: mvt method for 3 tests 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale
```

```r
contrast(emm, "revpairwise", by = "Field_Type", adjust = "mvt")
#> Field_Type = not sown:
#>  contrast    ratio    SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  75m / 50m   0.692 0.300 Inf    1  -0.848  0.8307
#>  150m / 50m  1.231 0.460 Inf    1   0.556  0.9446
#>  150m / 75m  1.778 0.741 Inf    1   1.381  0.5100
#>  200m / 50m  0.846 0.347 Inf    1  -0.408  0.9770
#>  200m / 75m  1.222 0.549 Inf    1   0.446  0.9702
#>  200m / 150m 0.688 0.269 Inf    1  -0.957  0.7731
#> 
#> Field_Type = grassland:
#>  contrast    ratio    SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  75m / 50m   1.151 0.216 Inf    1   0.749  0.8749
#>  150m / 50m  0.925 0.183 Inf    1  -0.396  0.9785
#>  150m / 75m  0.803 0.154 Inf    1  -1.142  0.6587
#>  200m / 50m  2.906 0.463 Inf    1   6.698  <.0001
#>  200m / 75m  2.525 0.382 Inf    1   6.121  <.0001
#>  200m / 150m 3.143 0.515 Inf    1   6.982  <.0001
#> 
#> Field_Type = production:
#>  contrast    ratio    SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  75m / 50m   2.073 0.340 Inf    1   4.440  <.0001
#>  150m / 50m  2.200 0.358 Inf    1   4.848  <.0001
#>  150m / 75m  1.061 0.139 Inf    1   0.457  0.9676
#>  200m / 50m  3.945 0.596 Inf    1   9.092  <.0001
#>  200m / 75m  1.904 0.220 Inf    1   5.565  <.0001
#>  200m / 150m 1.793 0.203 Inf    1   5.148  <.0001
#> 
#> P value adjustment: mvt method for 6 tests 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale
```

Finally, the distances are ordered (though the model ignores this fact), so we might not be interested in all possible pairwise distance comparisons. Here is how to look at "successive" distance pairs only; since we make fewer comparisons we apply smaller multiple comparison adjustment. This is reasonable if we believe (a priori) that the relationship between abundance rate and distance is monotonic.

```r
contrast(emm,
  method = list(
    "75m - 50m" = c(-1, 1, 0, 0),
    "150m - 75m" = c(0, -1, 1, 0),
    "200m - 150m" = c(0, 0, -1, 1)
  ),
  by = "Field_Type",
  adjust = "mvt"
)
#> Field_Type = not sown:
#>  contrast    ratio    SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  75m / 50m   0.692 0.300 Inf    1  -0.848  0.7341
#>  150m / 75m  1.778 0.741 Inf    1   1.381  0.3805
#>  200m / 150m 0.688 0.269 Inf    1  -0.957  0.6607
#> 
#> Field_Type = grassland:
#>  contrast    ratio    SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  75m / 50m   1.151 0.216 Inf    1   0.749  0.7859
#>  150m / 75m  0.803 0.154 Inf    1  -1.142  0.5217
#>  200m / 150m 3.143 0.515 Inf    1   6.982  <.0001
#> 
#> Field_Type = production:
#>  contrast    ratio    SE  df null z.ratio p.value
#>  75m / 50m   2.073 0.340 Inf    1   4.440  <.0001
#>  150m / 75m  1.061 0.139 Inf    1   0.457  0.9429
#>  200m / 150m 1.793 0.203 Inf    1   5.148  <.0001
#> 
#> P value adjustment: mvt method for 3 tests 
#> Tests are performed on the log scale
```

---

R code to simulate a dataset and reproduce the analysis:

```r
library("emmeans")
library("glmmTMB")
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1234)

params <- tribble(
  ~Field_Type, ~distance, ~rate,
  "not sown", "50m", 0.2,
  "not sown", "75m", 0.2,
  "not sown", "150m", 0.2,
  "not sown", "200m", 0.2,
  "grassland", "50m", 1,
  "grassland", "75m", 1,
  "grassland", "150m", 1,
  "grassland", "200m", 3,
  "production", "50m", 1,
  "production", "75m", 2,
  "production", "150m", 2,
  "production", "200m", 4
)
params <- params %>%
  mutate(
    Field_Type = factor(Field_Type,
      levels = c("not sown", "grassland", "production")
    ),
    distance = factor(distance,
      levels = c("50m", "75m", "150m", "200m")
    )
  )
params

OWL6 <-
  crossing(
    params,
    LS = 1:18
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    re = rnorm(n(), sd = 0.1)
  ) %>%
  crossing(
    sampling.round = 1:3
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Abundace = rpois(n(), exp(log(rate) + re))
  )

model1 <- glmmTMB(
  Abundace ~ Field_Type + distance + Field_Type * distance + (1 | LS),
  family = poisson(link = "log"),
  data = OWL6
)

summary(model1, "fixed")

emm <- emmeans(model1, c("Field_Type", "distance"), type = "response")
emm

contrast(emm, "pairwise", by = "distance", adjust = "mvt")
contrast(emm, "revpairwise", by = "Field_Type", adjust = "mvt")

contrast(emm,
  method = list(
    "75m - 50m" = c(-1, 1, 0, 0),
    "150m - 75m" = c(0, -1, 1, 0),
    "200m - 150m" = c(0, 0, -1, 1)
  ),
  by = "Field_Type",
  adjust = "mvt"
)

as_tibble(emm) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(distance, rate,
      group = Field_Type,
      color = Field_Type
    )
  ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(distance, rate, group = Field_Type),
    position = position_nudge(x = 0.1),
    data = params,
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    shape = 4
  ) +
  geom_pointrange(
    aes(
      ymin = asymp.LCL,
      ymax = asymp.UCL
    ),
    size = 0.1
  ) +
  facet_grid(
    ~Field_Type
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much for this!

Comment: I also wanted to ask about the emmeans output and it's interpretion. So the ratio shows me (for example : 75m / 50m   ratio= 0.692 ), that there is a 0.692 ratio difference in the two real values and the p-value shows if it is significant? Second question: Contrast (pairwise and revpeirwise test are performed on log sacale, so the results are also in log scale?

Comment: The Poisson regression is modeling the expected abundance $\operatorname{E}(Y|X)$ on the log scale: $\log\operatorname{E}(Y|X) = \beta X$. (This is basically about the link function in a GLM.) Because of the link, we can choose two scales at which to calculate the pairwise comparisons. We can compare $\log \operatorname{E}(Y|X_A) - \log \operatorname{E}(Y|X_B)$ where $X_A$ and $X_B$ are two difference predictor settings (such as 50m and 75m). This is on the link scale (or the log scale since the link function is log in this case).

Comment: Or we can compare $\operatorname{E}(Y|X_A) / \operatorname{E}(Y|X_B)$. This effectively transforms the comparison from the log scale back to the scale on which abundance is measured. So this is the original scale or response scale. You can change the scale with the `type` parameter in this call: `emmeans(model1, c("Field_Type", "distance"), type = "response")`. To explain the interpretation well it's important to understand how the link function works. The emmeans [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) are well written and a good place to start.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for taking the time to explain this to me :)